# Error when injecting $location into config

Tags: angularjs

I need to use $location.path() in the routes, but gets an "Unknown provider: $location" when trying to inject it.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider','$location', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider,$location) {

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $location
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$locationProvider` is used for the configuration.
All the configuration for using `$location` should be done with `$locationProvider`. So you should not inject it in the config.Read about all the configurations available for $location service here:[$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)